# Magento multistore default settings

Tags: magento, settings, default

I have a problem (suddenly) with the defaults settings for a product. We have a multistore setup with several languages. When we create a new product, we put in alle relevant data for the product.
When we switch to another store view, all the "Use Default Value" checkboxes are unchecked. 
Normally they should be checked by default, now it is unchecked by default?

We only need to change some things to another language, most things should keep the default setting.

This started a few days ago, the only thing we changed on the setup during that time is adding some extra modules or emptyd some log tables in the database?

Does anyone have any clue where I can correct this behaviour and have all the "Use Default Value" checkboxes checked by default again?

Answer (score 0):

be sure that in file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml or (find the same file in your custom admin theme if You use it) in line 55 input has attribute checked="checked". 
Also check in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element method usedDefault()  and see you error logs.

Comment: Hi, the files seems to be okay. I'm not sure what error log to check? Could it be a database issue?